# Proving that this is not a group.

Tags: group-theory, self-learning

I got the set: $G=\{p/q\in \Bbb Q : (p,q)=1$, with $q$ odd number $\}$ and the binary operation $a*b:=a+b$. And I say that $(G.*)$ isn't a group because it doesn't have an identity.

My proof is: We know that $G$ is a subset of rational numbers, then $e$ must be $0$, but since $0\not\in G$ then $G$ doesn't have an identity. Is this correct?

In general could it happen that if we've got a subset of a group, this could have a different identity?

Comment: Why do you say that " e must be 0"?

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar because the operation is $+$ and $0$ is the number that I know works for rationals

Comment: Why do you think $0\not\in G$? What is the gcd of $0$ and $1$?

Comment: 0=0/1. It has an odd denominator!

Comment: @Abodi: Thanks. I understand now.

Comment: To answer your last question: suppose $S$ is a subset of $G$ and $S$ contains some element $y$ such that $x*y=x$ for all $x\in S$. For any given $x\in S$ we can multiply both sides of the equation $x*y=x$ on the left by $x^{-1}\in G$ and obtain $y=e$, the identity element of $G$. (This is assuming that the operation $*$ on $S$ is consistent with the one on $G$.)

Comment: I messed up, for some reason I thought that (0,1) wasn't 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\frac{p_1}{q_1},\frac{p_2}{q_2}\in G$ then $\frac{p_1}{q_1}+\frac{p_2}{q_2}=\frac{p_1q_2+p_2q_1}{q_1q_2}$. Now the numerator may be even but the denominator isn't. So when the common primes are cancelled out we cannot have an even denominator. So $G$ is closed. Clearly all inverses are in $G$ as well following which it is a group.

Comment: You say "G is closed" that means if $a,b\in G$ then $a*b\in G$ (?), but in the book I'm reading (Rotman), doesn't says anything about G being closed in the definition of group

Comment: Oh wait... I think I understand now, is it closed because of the definition of binary operation?

Comment: @Abodi: Yes I mean that. Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: It's quite alright, I'm a neophyte anyway

Answer (score 3):

You're half-correct: If $G$ were a group, then it would be a subset of $\mathbb{Q}$ with the *same* operation as $(\mathbb{Q}, +)$, so the only possible identity would be $0$.

But since $0 = \frac 0 1$ and $\gcd(0, 1) = 1$ is odd, this doesn't actually give a counterexample.

---

More generally, if $G$ is a group, and $H$ is a subset of $G$ with the *same* operation, and $H$ is a group under this operation, then the identities of $H$ and $G$ coincide.